# TextBox Loses Focus with jquery autocomplete select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been using jquery autocomplete, as soon as i select the value from autocomplete drop down textbox loses the focus,

How can i prevent it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#<%=search.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Search.ashx", {
            width: 153, scrollHeight: 250,
            close: function(event, ui) { alert("close"); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    'select':function(){
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

That should do it, although that will go to the end of line where someone typed from... I guess that's up to you where you choose to maintain values of input caret position and utilise appropriately. If you need help with that I'd look up the `select` event on the jQuery API.